# Are there SO moderators who are not listed on the users page (moderators tab)?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I stumbled across [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14984460/charlee) who is a moderator (and also a staff member):

[image]

I don't see this name in the [main SO moderators list](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

I was wondering what the circumstances are, here.

Comment: I guess it's simply because staffs have superpowers.

Comment: Member for 33 days, too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Charlee is a member of staff, and is **not** a community moderator.  Staff can have moderator *access*, but are never elected moderators.

Not all staff needs moderator access, most people working at the company don’t need that level of control and privileged access. Almost invariably, staff with moderator access will have such access *across the whole network of Stack Exchange sites*.

The *moderators* tab only lists *Community Moderators*, which are elected members of the community (some of our longest serving moderators were *appointed* rather than elected). Staff can’t be community moderators.

Community Moderators only have moderator access on the site(s) they were elected on. E.g. I am a Community Moderator here on Stack Overflow, and nowhere else on the network. Some of my fellow moderators hold moderator positions on multiple sites, but never on all.

Comment: So staff are actually prohibited from nominating themselves and running for elections?

Comment: @cigien in all cases were elected moderators were hired and became staff they laid down their moderator position. There are also examples of ex-employees that have become moderators (or were re-instated) after leaving the company. I don’t know if there is an official policy in place but the evidence suggests that there is one.

Comment: @cigien [staff can't run for elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340713/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah, I see, there is official policy. Thanks for the link.

Comment: "never on all"... Why do you challenge ChrisF like that?